# How to set a window icon with PyQt5?

Tags: python, icons, pyqt5, qmainwindow, python-3.6

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt5.QtCore import *

class Application(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Application, self).__init__()
        self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
```

I am trying to set a window icon (top left of the window) but the normal icon disappeared instead.

I tried with many icon resolutions (8x8, 16x16, 32x32, 64x64) and extensions (.png and .ico).

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Use an absolute path.

Comment: Thank you but it's not working. I tried with         self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('C:/Users/John/PycharmProjects/pythonproject/icon.png')).  Also, I had to add QtGui in the import to get QIcon. I am not even sure it is the good way to do it with PyQt5.

Comment: Oh I found my mistake, I thought my icon was white on black, but in fact it was white on transparent. Everything is working right with         self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png')) . My bad, Thank you very much for the help ekhumoro!

Answer (score 16):

The command, as suggested by asker, works for me:

```
 self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon('icon.png'))
```

I put 256x256 png and all was OK. I have Win 7 pro 64 bit, Python 3.5.2 32 bit.

Answer (score 10):

The answer has been given by the asker (invisible icon). I wanted to add that the script may not be executed in the script directory. In any case, to be safe, you may want to make sure the icon is loaded relative to the directory in which the script resides:

```
import os 
# [...]
scriptDir = os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__))
self.setWindowIcon(QtGui.QIcon(scriptDir + os.path.sep + 'logo.png'))
```

Comment: This is the only thing that worked for me! Thanks alot!!!

Answer (score 1):

I'm using PyQT5. And code should be as...

```
icon = QtGui.QIcon()
icon.addPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("programmer.png"), QtGui.QIcon.Selected, QtGui.QIcon.On)
MainWindow.setWindowIcon(icon)
```

Comment: I'm always receiving " QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap ".

Answer (score 0):

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon


class Example(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.initUI()


    def initUI(self):

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 220)
        self.setWindowTitle('Icon')
        self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('web.png'))
```

Comment: I'm always receiving " QPixmap: Must construct a QGuiApplication before a QPixmap ".

Answer (score 0):

```py
from PyQt5.QtGui import QIcon

self.setWindowIcon(QIcon('Notepad_Vista_10.png'))
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I agree with @Friedrich... your answer is unclear. Please edit to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.   Without more explanation I will recommend deletion of your answer.

Comment: How tf is this unclear its literally the answer its 1 line of Code that solves this issue. How is Santanu Pal`s answer not unclear then